# Drawing rectangle doesn't work

Tags: c#, forms, graphics, drawing, shapes

Can you explain me what's wrong with this code? because it is not drawing anything.
doesn't it suppose to draw a rectangle in my form? thanks!

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 150, 150);
        g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `CreateGraphics`.  You cannot keep it refreshed.  It _is_ working...you just don't have time to see it before the surface refreshes.

Comment: Move this code (w/o Creategraphics) to the Paint event. And make sure there are no Controls (Panels) in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your painting in the `OnPaint` method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 150, 150);
    g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, r);
}
```

Comment: While this might work...it's a poor suggestion.  Overriding the `OnPaint` in a `Form` is a bad idea.  Better to add a control to the form that you render.  Short of a silly exercise, this is likely to provide poor long term results.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I didn't know what the OP want to achieve, I simply point out that to draw on a control (a `Form` in this case) the right way is in the `OnPaint` method.

Comment: what control should i add?

Comment: Take a look at [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.